# How do I make my Tor Browser a relay?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays

I have the updated version of Tor, but there is no console after the Tor connection is made and the browser comes up. I would like to run a Tor relay but am unable to due to lack of Tor console. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Hugh, I edited your title so it's more attention-grabbing from the questions page. Feel free to tweak with another [edit] if needed.

Comment: +1, good point, I hadn't thought of this with the new release. (I love the new version BTW,) and I'd think this should be simple, however a quick glance through the menus (on a Mac) turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running a Tor relay separate from your Tor Browser Bundle's Tor client instance.  This way, you can leave the relay up when you restart your Tor Browser Bundle, and the configurations won't collide.

Some examples:

For Mac OS X, you can use the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) package system to 'sudo port install tor', or use [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/installation) to 'brew install tor' or use [Homebrew recipes for development versions of Tor](https://github.com/mtigas/homebrew-tor).  See also [Tor Project: Mac OS X Install Instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) for more Homebrew and configuration ideas. All those will install a system or user Tor binary for the relay to use.

For Debian/Ubuntu, the [Tor relay configuration instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en) state the following:

> **Do not use the packages in Ubuntu's universe.** If you're on Ubuntu or if you want to track newer Tor packages, follow the [Tor on Ubuntu or Debian](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) instructions to use our repository.

On MS Windows, check the [Tor Project's package repository](https://www.torproject.org/dist/vidalia-bundles/) for an appropriate relay bundle.

For all of those, you will want to also read up on [Configuring a Tor relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en).

And most importantly, thank you for running a relay.

Answer (score 0):

Tor's official instructions on how to run a relay:

https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/relays.html.en

Comment: Can you please copy the main points here or give a slight overview? A good rule of thumb is that all SE answers should fully answer the question without requiring the user to leave the site or click on links which might be broken in a few years time. Thanks!